# Trouble with progressbar

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, progress-bar

So i have a weird problem. I have Layout looking like this:

```
<LinearLayout      
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:id="@+id/myText" />

     <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarHorizontal"            
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

It looks simple but my application does not start. I have no error, but application can not start. But if i remove  tag from Layout application starts successfully. 
I can not understand where i am wrong. Could someone help me?

Comment: Did you set the progress bar style? I'm not aware of how it behaves by default... `style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"`

Comment: try adding `max` and `progress` attributes to the `ProgressBar` tag

Answer (score 0):

This layout can't work because you did not set the layout_width and the layout_height attribute of the LinearLayout.
Try to add

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to your LinearLayout.

As said [here: (Layouts: Layout Parameters)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#layout-params)

> All view groups include a width and height (layout_width and layout_height), and each view is required to define them.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't necessarily with your layout (while you're missing required attributes, it's likely you're getting these filled in for you by your IDE), it's with the definition of the `ProgressBar`.

You're missing the required style attribute that tells the framework which widget to render.

If you use this in your layout, the resulting effect (if it even starts) is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/my_text"
            />
    <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="209dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Result:
[image: Sadface]

If you define the style attribute like the code below, your result will be much better:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/my_text"
            />
    <ProgressBar
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="209dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar" android:progress="35"/>          
</LinearLayout>
```

Result:
[image]